# PHP Variable object names?

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON object which I have decoded.  I know that to access the data from the object, you would normally:

```
$value = $obj->data
```

Consider the following, where  is a variable returned from the curl request

```
stdClass Object
(
    [<account_name>] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 123
        [name] => "Some Name"
        [email] = "someguy@somemail.net"
    )
)
```

How do I get the values of `[id]`, `[name]`, `[email]` etc, if I do not know the object key?

Comment: Use json_decode($json,true); it will give you an array then lopp through and useing foreach($data as $key=>$val) you will get the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `json_decode`, set the second parameter to `true` to decode the json data to an array.

Then you could use `foreach` to loop the array even you do not know the key.

Answer (score 0):

This function will most likely be able to help you. [Get_Object_vars](http://php.net/get_object_vars)